# Why am I having problems with "large" matrices in sage?

Tags: python, matrix, indexoutofboundsexception, sage

I'm trying to do some computations with a 22x22 matrix in sage. This doesn't seem like it should be that bad to do, in particular since the matrix is pretty sparse. However, when I try to do anything with the matrix I get an "IndexError: string index out of range", or nonsense computations. What gives?

Even very simply, if I try the following code:

> M = matrix(ZZ,20); M

This should display a 20x20 matrix of zeros. However, it instead gives the same IndexError, where

> M = matrix(ZZ,19); M

does not, and gives exactly what you expect.

The funny thing is that having inputted my matrix, any attempt to display it gives the IndexError. However, there are still a few things that I can do that give "answers", although I'm skeptical about their correctness. For example, I can do things like

> M.parent()

which seems to make sense. However,

> M.determinant()

spits out a number, but I'm about 99% certain that the number it gives me has little to do with the determinant of the matrix that I've put in.

So what's up? Is sage just incapable of dealing with matrices greater than size 19x19?

Edit: This is on Mac OS X 10.9.4, and my sage version is 5.10. This is after a fresh restart of sage, which gives me the same error. However, it seems that I should probably update sage and see if it keeps up with the problem....

Comment: What version of Sage? What platform? These commands all work for me in Sage 6.2.

Comment: I'd recommend restarting Sage - maybe you defined something strange and forgot about it and that messed things up (like `i=4` and then forgetting about having done it when you want the (a) square root of -1).  This has happened to me plenty.  Otherwise I agree that more technical info will be really helpful.

Comment: Actually, on further investigation, I only get this error if I am using the sage notebook. If I don't use the notebook, but only the shell, then from n=19 to n=20 it won't give the error, but it will display it differently: it returns "20 x 20 dense matrix over Integer Ring (type 'print M.str()' to see all of the entries)", which prints properly if I type the given command. This suggests that sage 5.10 treats 20x20 matrices different than smaller ones...

Comment: Sage has treated 20x20 (and larger) matrices differently from smaller ones for a while, the idea being that large ones are often too big to print by default. (Imagine if they're 1000x1000, for example.) By the way, I've now also tried this on Sage 5.11, and it works there, too. I can try on some older versions if that's worthwhile, but I don't have time right now. I don't know what's causing your trouble, but you should update; version 5.10 is more than a year old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known and fixed bug, see tickets [#14785](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/14785)
and [#14579](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/14579) on
[Sage's trac](http://trac.sagemath.org/), where we learn that the bug was in Python,
see [issue 17526](http://bugs.python.org/issue17526) on 
[Python's bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/),
that it was resovled upstream, and that this works well in Sage since version 5.11.beta3.

I agree with John Palmieri's encouragement to update. Sage gets better and better, so it's
always worth working with a recent version. Currently Sage 6.2 is out, and Sage 6.3.rc1 is
out and works well, so Sage 6.3 should be released pretty soon.

Regarding the determinant, I would be very surprised if it is computed incorrectly, but
why don't you check by computing it in another computer algebra system? If it is indeed
incorrect, please report the bug. Search the web for 'wims determinant' for an online
determinant calculator.

Edit (2014-08-10):
[Sage 6.3 is out!](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sage-release/Ilt8TZdy3H8/discussion)

And while I'm editing I'll link to the
[wims matrix tool](http://wims.unice.fr/~wims/en_tool~linear~matrix.html),
just for completeness.
I also confess that I haven't checked who Wims and Sage call for computing such a
determinant; it might end up being the same software, so that wouldn't be much
of a check. It's good that you checked it another way.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be fixed now. Regarding the determinant---it turns out that I had a flawed assumption. I assumed that the matrix should be of full rank, but it kept giving zero as a determinant even when I fiddled around with random coefficients. Turns out the matrix has (and should have!) much lower rank, hence the constant zero determinant.